# Android Media Recording fail on Nexus 5 (Lollipop)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

I have a working peace of code. It was written and tested on Samsung Android Camera EK-GC110 (Android 4.1.2) and it works great.

Code initiates new Media Recorder instance and prepares it for video recording:

- 5000 kbps bitrate
- 20 fps
- time limited
- no audio

When I run the app on my Nexus 5 (Android 5.0.1) phone I get:  start failed: -19 error and empty mp4 file.

**Code:**

```
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    camera.unlock();
    long duration = calculateDuration();
    MAX_DURATION = (int)duration/1000; 
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);

    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(5000000);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(20);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(1280,720);

    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration((int)duration); // Set max duration
    mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(this);

    String root = getSDCardPath();
    directory = new File(root + "/FileUpload/");
    if (!directory.exists())
        directory.mkdirs();

    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String uniqueOutFile = root + "/FileUpload/"
            + timeFormatter.format(currentTime)
            + ".mp4";
    File outFile = new File(directory, uniqueOutFile);
    if (outFile.exists()) {
        outFile.delete();
    }
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(uniqueOutFile);

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    mediaRecorder.start();
```

**Error stack:**

```
02-25 11:04:04.186  22334-22334/com.vp.fileupload.app I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 22334 SIG: 9
02-25 11:04:05.467  22470-22470/com.vp.fileupload.app I/MediaRecorderJNI﹕ prepare: surface=0xaf251400
02-25 11:04:05.557  22470-22470/com.vp.fileupload.app E/MediaRecorder﹕ start failed: -19
02-25 11:04:05.564  22470-22470/com.vp.fileupload.app D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
02-25 11:04:05.567  22470-22470/com.vp.fileupload.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vp.fileupload.app, PID: 22470
    java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
            at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
            at com.vp.fileupload.app.BackgroundVideoRecorder.cameraStart(BackgroundVideoRecorder.java:178)
            at com.vp.fileupload.app.BackgroundVideoRecorder.surfaceCreated(BackgroundVideoRecorder.java:85)
            at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:579)
            at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:176)
            at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1956)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that the hardware does not support capture on 20 fps. Try removing the setting of fps and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set profile instead of custom record parameters.

```
mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P));
```